# NSTextField inside NSStatusBar: focus and editable problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

My Cocoa App is made by a  **NSStatusBar** with a **NSTextField** inside and a Main Window.
Please, look the screenshots to get the idea:

[image]

I have two problems:

1. When I open Menubar  I am unable to got the focus to SearchField (like Spotlight) and 
   I am unable to select content with something like *[textField selectText:self]*
2. Worsts: if my MainWindow is on front it works without problems. If my MainWindow is not on front but is visible **I am unable to edit TextField**. It is selectable with mouse but not editable. Why this ?

[image]

I tried all the hacks found but I was unable to solve the issue.

Comment: @pierocampanelli did you ever get a solution to this? I've got a similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have also had this problem so I ended up completely recreating `NSMenu` using a `NSWindow`. I named it `JGMenuWindow` and you can find the open source code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/SquaredTiki/JGMenuWindow).

Here's an example of what it can do:

[image]

Comment: I've been putting off writing one of these for a while now. Thank you so much!